# Qt - SIGNAL & SLOT are not updating my QLabel in mainwindow from a worker class

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, loops, signals-slots

I applied an C++ example of working with threads in Qt 5.7. All things are good except two things:

1- I used Signal & Slot to update my label in the main form. the problem is that is no effect. Really, I don't know where is the issue.

2- The loop works fine, but when I exit my program I see (throught the "Application Output") that the loop still work (I think that's related with the started thread).

This my little example:

---

### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();  

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void updateLabelText(const QString TheString);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "worker.h"

//#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QThread *workerThread = new QThread;
    Worker *worker  = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(sendText(const QString)), this, SLOT(updateLabelText(QString)));
    workerThread->start();
}

void  MainWindow::updateLabelText(const QString TheString)
{
    ui->label->setText(TheString);
}
```

### worker.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Worker();

public slots:
    void doWork();

signals:
  void sendText(const QString);

};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

### worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QApplication>

Worker::Worker()
{
    doWork();
}

void Worker::doWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<999999; i++) {
        emit sendText(QString::number(i));
        qDebug() << "The number is : " + QString::number(i);
        qApp->processEvents();
        //QThread::msleep(5);
    }
}
```

---

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `doWork()` function is called from the `Worker`'s constructor, the constructor is invoked in the main thread (that is done in the line `Worker* worker= new Worker;`).

Of course, that is not what you meant to do, since it will cause the main thread to execute the `for` loop in `doWork()` before even reaching into the `connect` call.

Instead of calling `doWork()` from the `Worker`'s constructor, you should connect the thread's [`started()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#started) signal to `doWork()` slot, then call `thread->start()` after moving the `Worker` object to the new thread. This will leverage Qt cross-thread signals to invoke `doWork()` in the new thread as soon as it starts.

Here is how your code should look like:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

//QThread wrapper for safe destruction
//see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19666329
class Thread : public QThread{
    using QThread::run; //final
public:
    Thread(QObject* parent= nullptr): QThread(parent){}
    ~Thread(){ quit(); wait();}

};

class Worker : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject* parent= nullptr): QObject(parent){}
    ~Worker()= default;

    Q_SIGNAL void sendText(QString text);
    Q_SIGNAL void workFinished();

    Q_SLOT void doWork(){
        for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
            emit sendText(QString::number(i));
            QThread::msleep(5);
        }
        emit workFinished();
    }
};

class Widget : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget* parent= nullptr): QWidget(parent){
        layout.addWidget(&buttonWork);
        layout.addWidget(&label);

        connect(&buttonWork, &QPushButton::clicked,
                this, &Widget::buttonWorkClicked);

    }
    ~Widget()= default;

    Q_SLOT void buttonWorkClicked(){
        Thread* thread= new Thread(this);
        Worker* worker= new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(thread);
        //invoke doWork as soon as the thread is started
        connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::sendText, this, &Widget::updateLabelText);
        //quit the thread when work is finished
        connect(worker, &Worker::workFinished, thread, &QThread::quit);
        //destroy thread and worker object when work is finished
        connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(thread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        //start the thread
        thread->start();
    }

    Q_SLOT void updateLabelText(QString text){
        label.setText(text);
    }

private:
    QVBoxLayout layout{this};
    QPushButton buttonWork{"Work"};
    QLabel label{"No work yet"};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following the comment of Mr @Mike.

Simply, I removed the doWork() function from the instructor. Then, I added new connection between the thread's started() SIGNAL and worker's doWork() SLOT.

So thes are the changes:

---

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "worker.h"

#include <QThread>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QThread *workerThread = new QThread;
    Worker *worker  = new Worker;
    connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(doWork()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(sendText(const QString)), this, SLOT(updateLabelText(const QString)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
    worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
    workerThread->start();
}
void  MainWindow::updateLabelText(const QString TheString)
{
    ui->label->setText(TheString);
}
```

### worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QApplication>

Worker::Worker()
{
    doWork();
}

void Worker::doWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<999999; i++) {
        emit sendText(QString::number(i));
        qDebug() << "The number is : " + QString::number(i);
        qApp->processEvents();
        QThread::msleep(5);
    }
}
```